# N Requests made to a GPU instance that is always on

Tags: gpu

I was wondering if I could use ollama with any of their models on a GPU provider and get billed only for its usage ?

Like I want my website which would be on digitalocean or the like, but the AI calls would be on a GPU provider - so if I made some 5000 calls to my AI models on the GPU provider, would I be billed $XXX or only when the calls to the 5000 requests were made ?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK most of GPU provider charge by hours no matter if you use their GPU or not during the instance is turned on. However, AWS SageMaker async inference do support auto scaling and when there is no request to a instance for a configured time, it will be turned off hence save some money. If real-time performance is not an issue, you can also use SageMaker batch inference. Basically you accumulate the requests first, then run inference all at once, then turn off the instance until the next time the requests are accumulated.